# Cannot read property ‘plugins’ of undefined?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I installed ngCordova and included the js properly, I added the dependency too to my module, then I add clipboard plugin, then I do this code in my mainCtrl

```
  $cordovaClipboard
    .copy('text to copy')
    .then(function () {
      // success
      alert('copied');
    }, function () {
      // error
    });
```

I gotten the error of Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined, I guess I've done everything correctly? What might me the cause, any idea guys? No clue here what's going on..

Comment: How are you testing ? Device/emulator or in browsers ? Most of the plugins will work only on device/emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to emulate or deploy directly to the device to avoid this error. I notice also that if the app is hosted on https://apps.ionic.io/apps and rendered through Ionic View the native functionality still don't work for ngCodova